# Cooldown on a Button?

Tags: vb.net

I want a button on my form to only be allowed to use every ten minutes. I would use a timer, but I don't want the user to be able to exploit using the button again (resetting the cooldown) when they reopen the program.

Is there a way to do this? I appreciate any replies.

Answer (score 0):

A timer is possible but if you do not want to use one, you can create a settings file.. A plain text file or something in some folder. There you can keep track of the number of seconds 'left' before he can use the button again

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t4kyezf.aspx